IDEA version 4.1 issues
IDEA version 4.1: There is no Dependency option in Alt+Insetrt shortcut when adding jar packages from local repositories in the pom.xml file of a maven project.The Dependency option was available in the old version but not in the new one.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/Cleru.png)
